# Swarm ethereum installation in windows

Tags: swarm

[image]I tried to install swarm in windows.swarm comes up with mist browser .after that I have started running a private block chain using my custom genesis bloc and started running swarm using this below command swarm --bzzaccount BZZKEY .this command have started the swarm but i am getting an error when i try to access the http://127.0.0.1:8500/..Any Help on this ....

Hmmmmm....Swarm was not able to serve your request! Error message: Bad request GET : Invalid URI "/": unknown scheme "" Error code: 400[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XRk3.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not asking for any content in the url.

Furthermore, if you use a private blockchain, any ENS requests (the ethereum DNS) won't work unless you set up a resolver yourself, which is a bit involved, and probably better left for later after you get the basics working.

Judging from how you ask your question, I would recommend you to read the documentation thoroughly to get a good grasp on what swarm is and how it is intended to work. You can find it here:

https://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/